# SharePoint Content Editor not displaying page correctly

Tags: css, content-management-system, sharepoint-2013

I've built a page using HTML and
            CSS.
           When I bring is up in IE it displays fine. However when I link to it in 
          the Content Link in the Content Editor it knocks out all the formatting 
         and displays weirdly (as pictured). Help! Tried putting it in an
iframe, but can't get it to work. Is SharePoint forcing it's own CSS 
          onto the page? How do I stop it?

Here is the code, I need to know where to add code to break the SharePoint CSS.

```
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0jxu.png


    <script type="text/javascript">



    $.extend({
    getUrlVars: function(){
     var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?')   
    +     1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
     {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
     }
     return vars;
     },
      getUrlVar: function(name){
      return $.getUrlVars()[name];
    }
    });

   $(document).ready(function(){

    var byName = $.getUrlVar('IsDlg');
    if(byName == '1') {
    $('DIV[id="s4-leftpanel"]').hide();
    };
    });
    </script><html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"   
    xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"><head>

    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
    <mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
    <mso:_dlc_DocId msdt:dt="string">GENIE4-597-583</mso:_dlc_DocId>
    <mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid msdt:dt="string">6dfabe3c-9859-478a-8fe7- 
     de9184827a8c</mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid>

     <mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl  
     msdt:dt="string">http://genie.norgine.com/IT/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx? 
     ID=GENIE4-597-583, GENIE4-597-583</mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl>

     </mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
     </xml><![endif]-->
      <title></title></head>
       <body>



       <style>



     .main {
      margin: 0 auto ;
     max-width: 2000px;
    }

     .wrapper {

      box-sizing: border-box;
      background: #ffffff;

      }
     .box {
      width: 171px;
      height: 152px;
      margin: 2px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      float: left;
        }
      .topicImage{
      width: 302px;
     height: 152px;
     margin: 2px;
     float: left;
    }

    a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    </style>


     <div class="main" style="width:90%">
     <div class="topicImage"><img srcxxx.png" alt="Helpful information on  
     how 
     to manage and reset your   
     network password" alt="IT Services"> </div>
     <div>
      <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="PageContentStyleCustom"><div class="box"><a 
       href="/xxx.aspx">  <img style="border:0;"   
       src="/xxx.png" 
       alt="Helpful information on how to manage and reset your network 
         password"></div><!--
         --><div class="PageContentStyleCustom"><div class="box"><a 
        href="/xxx.aspx"> <img style="border:0;" 
        srcxxx" alt="Helpful  
       information on how to access/manage your email account, how to  
      identify 
        and block unwanted email"></div><!--
          --><div class="PageContentStyleCustom"><div class="box"><a 
        hrefxxx.aspx"> <img style="border:0;"  
        srcxxx.png" alt="Overview 
        of the rules on website restrictions and how to request access 
      to    
       blocked site"></div><!--
       --><div class="box"><a href="/xxx.aspx">  
        <img style="border:0;"srcxxx.png" alt="Click here for tips and 
      hints on 
       how to use Skype for Business"></div><!--
         --><div class="box"><a href="xxx.pdf"><img style="border:0;"src="" 
        alt="Information on joining the guest 
         WIFI"></div><!--
          --><div class="box">
        <a 
        href="xxx.qds"><img 
        style="border:0;"srcxxx.png"  
        alt="Click here to find and connect to a printer at your current 
         location"></div><!--              
          --><div class="box"><a hrefxxx.aspx"><img 
         style="border:0;"src="/xxx.png" alt="How to purchase Microsoft 
    Office 
     Professional at a discounted price"></div><!--
      --><div class="box"><a 
     href="xxx.hta">  <img 
     style="border:0;"src**xxx**.png" alt="Click there to update your  
     profile 
      information"></div></div>
        <a href="xxx/"><!--
          --><div class="box"><a 
         href="http:xxx/"><img 
          style="border:0;"src="/xxx" alt="Click here to manage and release 
         blocked emails"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"><a 
          href="http: xxx" ><img 
          style="border:0;"src="xxx.png" alt="Click here to raise a 
          request to create a new SharePoint site"></div><!--
           --><div class="box"><a href="xxx.aspx"><img style="border:0;"  
         srcxxx.PNG" alt=" "></div><!--
          --><div class="box"><a 

       href="http://xxx"></div><!--
        --><div class="box"><a href="xxx.pdf">  <img style="border:0;" src  
       xxx.png" alt="System register"></div><!--
       --><div class="box"><a hrefxxx.PNG" alt="Coming soon"></a></div>

     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Contents of the content editor webpart can be affected by style of the page because SharePoint is forcing its own CSS.

Make sure you do not use the classes of SharePoint and/or provide your own classes and styling to your content

Comment: Thanks, how do I make sure I don't use the SharePoint classes?

Comment: SharePoint classes normally begin by ```ms-``` prefix, if you have used any such classes, please use your own prefix

Comment: Thanks, I found this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms551040.aspx and I've tried adding the: <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id="Content" FieldName="PublishingPageContent" runat="server" PrefixStyleSheet-"PageContentStyle"/> line but it doesn't make a difference. Do I need to add that line in CSS and then add <div class> line for every image/link line of code?